# Import Spring Framework with Gradle 1.11 causes Multiple dex files define error

Tags: android, spring, gradle

According to Spring Framework Android [quickstart](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/), if you are using Gradle to build your project, you should add the following lines as build dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.+'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.+'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.+'
}
```

However, the following error happens on Gradle 1.11:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
            Lorg/springframework/core/ErrorCoded;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/android/743289-importing-android-spring-with-gradle-cause-error-mutiple-dex-files) thread at Spring.io, *"the Spring for Android rest-template and core artifacts do not have a dependency on spring core or any Spring Framework library. However, the auth dependency does, along with Spring Social"*.

Thus, a possible solution is marking these repeated dependencies for exclusion:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.+') {
        exclude group :'org.springframework', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group :'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
        exclude group :'org.springframework', module: 'spring-web'
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.+'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.+'
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples) you can find many Spring Android samples using Gradle 0.9 and Gradle 1.11.